# Where does the device list come from in Console.app? (Why are duplicate devices shown?)

Tags: macos, apple-watch, bug, console, sonoma

Sonoma 14.1.1 (23B81), Mac Mini M1 2020.

I noticed recently that Console.app is showing duplicate devices. E.g. screenshot below showing 4 of the same **ldh-watch** device (I have only 1 Apple Watch).

[image: console screenshot]

Anyone know where this list comes from, and how to reset/clear it?